# What star was the asteroid 2014 MU69 predicted to occult on 2018-08-04?

Tags: asteroids, hubble-telescope, occultation

From a search, I found a list of some [preparatory HST observations](https://archive.stsci.edu/proposal_search.php?id=15450&mission=hst) made for the August 4, 2018 occultation of a star by the asteroid 2014 MU69

> We propose observations in support of the upcoming New Horizons encounter for 2014MU69. One visit is for support observations of a star to be occulted by 2014MU69 on 2018 August 4 from which ultra-precise astrometry and shape information about the target can be derived. The second visit is for a backup epoch of astrometry on 2014MU69 itself at the end of the 2018 observing window at a time when New Horizons will also be observing the target. (minor typographical edits made)

Five lines are shown, for measurements between `2018-04-30 01:03` and `01:48`. The target is listed as `MU20180804` but that name seems to be the [identification of an occultation](https://www.boulder.swri.edu/~buie/occ/MU20180804.html), not the name of a star.

So far I have not figured out the actual identity of the star that was predicted to be occulted by 2014 MU69 on `2018-08-04`.

Here is a [very nice prediction](http://www.asteroidoccultation.com/observations/NA/MU69Binzel.pdf) for three occultations by 2014 MU69 last year (2017). However when I go to the [main page](http://www.asteroidoccultation.com/) for that asteroid occultation site and look at `2018-08-04` I don't see any events with MU69 as the asteroid!

See also [Will the upcoming observations of occultation by “Ultima Thule” (2014 MU69) be of a single object, or two?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29881/12102)

[image: Occultation by MU69 on 2018-08-04]

Comment: I thought that asteroids occult multiple stars seen from different parts of the world at different times on the same night. as illustrated by the image here: https://occultations.org/ ... and ... http://www.poyntsource.com/New/Global.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [VizieR query](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR) within 15 arcseconds of [Buie's coordinates](https://www.boulder.swri.edu/~buie/occ/MU20180804.html) returns a 13th magnitude star, variously identified as:

- 2MASS [19042146-2035362](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-5?-ref=VIZ5b6a57cb8ba7&-out.add=.&-source=II/246/out&2MASS===19042146-2035362&-out.orig=o)
- UCAC4 [348-170642](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-5?-ref=VIZ5b6a57e88eea&-out.add=.&-source=I/322A/out&UCAC4===348-170642&-out.orig=o)
- Gaia DR2 [4082342058110504064](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-5?-ref=VIZ5b6a4af18782&-out.add=.&-source=I/345/gaia2&-c=286.08948619284%20-20.59347479448,eq=ICRS,rs=0.005&-out.orig=o)

Comment: Speedy, aren't we?! :-)

Comment: Do you think there is a somewhat objective answer to [For stars around 13th magnitude, are their entries in various catalogues usually linked, or does one do this manually?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27278/7982)